# Facebook API: How to get a facebook post REAL shares count?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a website that needs to count the **number of shares of the URL of website** (diadesolidariedade.com.br) AND if possible, the count of **posts with hashtag "#JuntosFazemosoBem"** and the **number of shares of specific posts**, all in Facebook. Twitter counts too, but with Twitter is easier (they have a more flexible API).

I've already implemented the **count of shares of the URL** using this code:

```
function facebook_count($url){
    $fqlURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=".$url."&format=json";
    // Facebook Response is in JSON
    $response = file_get_contents($fqlURL);
    return json_decode($response);
}
$fb = facebook_count("diadesolidariedade.com.br");
$fb_count = $fb[0]->share_count;
```

*- there is another option with http://graph.facebook.com/?id=%%URL%%, but it returns the "share count", that counts likes, comments and shares.*

Then, i started to search options to get hashtag count and share count. Reading several topics here in StackOverflow and many other websites, i found that:

**HASHTAG COUNT:** it's not possible, because public feed search doesn't work anymore (/search?type=topic&q=lebron james&fields=id,name,page), unless you are an authorized partner of Facebook...

**SHARE COUNT:** it was possible with FQL. But FQL doesn't work anymore too.

Then i tried this code (with Facebook PHP SDK 2.3.2 and an App Access):

```
$page_id = "586319238075582";
$post_id = "883534958354007";

$query = $facebook->api('/'.$post_id.'?fields=sharedposts.fields(from)');
echo print_r($query);
?><br/>--------------------------------<br/><?
echo print_r($query["sharedposts"]["data"]);
```

With that code, i can have all the post info like comments and likes, but when i retrieve the SharedPosts array, it returns me only 10, when the real post have around 70 shares!

Is there any workaround to hashtags and share counts?

Thanks,
Henrique.

Answer (score 0):

To get number of shares for any URL just use Facebook's graph API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://example.com
```